# Using boost::filesystem::path as a key in an std::map

Tags: windows, boost, boost-filesystem

So std::map wants the key type to be ordered, but I ran into problems:

"a/b" < "a/c" < "a//b" but fs::equivalent("a/b", "a//b")

"a/b" < "a/c" < "a\b" but fs::equivalent("a/b", "a\b")

How I do I normalize a path enough to create an ordering? Is that even possible? I tried using path::generic_string() in a custom comparison operator, but it didn't work. fs::equivalent() doesn't help either, because implementing equality isn't enough for std::map, it needs an ordering. That's also the reason why this question isn't a duplicate of [How do I "normalize" a pathname using boost::filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746136/how-do-i-normalize-a-pathname-using-boostfilesystem).

Context: Windows only, Boost 1.49, filesystem3.

Comment: Those == you list there are not filesystem's operator== overloads, are they? The documentation lists a==b as !(a<b) && !(b<a), which contradicts what you wrote. So it would be a bug...

Comment: @ltjax Edited the == out, what I meant was equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make paths comparable you need to convert them to the **canonical** representation and then compare via string. A canonical path is absolute, normalized and has symbolic links removed. Boost offers canonical AFAIK. Because symbolic links need to be resolved, calling canonical requires access to the filesystem.

Comment: Nope: fs::canonical(fs::path("C:\\Temp\\boost\\test.txt")) -> "C:/Temp\boost\test.txt", but fs::canonical(fs::path("c:/temp//boost/test.txt")) -> "c:/temp\boost\test.txt".

Comment: Well, upon closer inspection, I guess it does everything I need except change the case. So boost::to_lower_copy(fs::canonical(path).string()) should do the trick.

Comment: Too bad that boost::fs does not tell you whether the fs is case-sensitive or not.