# How to resolve a file path

Tags: c++, qt, boost, filepath

I need to create a function that will remove anything such as '..' or '.' in a filepath. So if I did `resolvePath("/root\\\\directory1/directory2\\\\\\\\..")` it would return `"root/directory1`. I tried making a char* array of each part of the path but I couldn't get each segment of it.

Comment: any reason not to use boost::filesystem?

Comment: What do you mean? I am using it for an emulator and one of the functions is this.

Comment: You really need to post what you've tried so far and be more specific about where you got stuck.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746136/how-do-i-normalize-a-pathname-using-boostfilesystem
and read documentation about "canonical" function in boost::filesystem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two really cross-platform alternatives are boost and Qt for this, so here goes it with both demonstrated:

#### Boost solution: [boost::filesystem::canonical](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical)

```
path canonical(const path& p, const path& base = current_path());

path canonical(const path& p, system::error_code& ec);

path canonical(const path& p, const path& base, system::error_code& ec);
```

#### Qt solution:  [QFileInfo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#canonicalFilePath)

```
QFileInfo fileInfo("/root\\\\directory1/directory2\\\\\\\\.."))

qDebug() << fileInfo.canonicalFilePath();
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks from the example path you gave that you're on a Unix-like system.  You can use `realpath()` to canonicalize your path then.  This exists on Linux, BSD and Mac OS at least.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html

Answer (score 1):

**A working solution is now available from the standard libary (C++17):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
int main()
{
    // resolves based on current dir
    std::filesystem::path mypath = std::filesystem::canonical("../dir/file.ext");
    std::cout << mypath.generic_string(); // root/parent_dir/dir/file.ext
    return 0;
}
```

Documentation:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem