# Cross-platform alternative to this realpath definition?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, realpath

So, someone recently submitted some bug fixes to my project, and they also included this:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #ifndef PATH_MAX
    #define PATH_MAX _MAX_PATH
    #endif
    #define realpath(N,R) _fullpath((R),(N),_MAX_PATH)
#endif
```

The problem is I'm using Code::Blocks with MinGW, so when I try to compile, it says that realpath() isn't defined at all. The submitter didn't provide any alternative, and when I try to search for realpath without MSVC, all I get is using realpath *with* MSVC. Does anyone have something I can use with MinGW instead?

Answer (score 3):

`realpath()` is a POSIX function which is why it is not found by MinGW. What you could do is use the boost::filesystem library as a cross-platform alternative to find the absolute path. A tutorial for boost::filesystem is available below:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm#tutorial

There have already been some questions on the boost::filesystem library.
A link to one which may be useful has been attached below:

[How do I "normalize" a pathname using boost::filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746136/how-do-i-normalize-a-pathname-using-boostfilesystem)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Comment: @KelvinShadewing If you have found this answer useful can you please accept it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following adjustment on the `#ifdef` condition worked:

```c
/* Create a realpath replacement macro for when compiling under mingw
 * Based upon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124869/cross-platform-alternative-to-this-realpath-definition
 */
#ifdef WIN32
    #define realpath(N,R) _fullpath((R),(N),PATH_MAX)
#endif
```

In both cases the generated executables were run on Windows 10.
Tested using:

- The MinGW64 native Windows mex compiler packaged by MATLAB 2021a.
- The `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` 7.3-win32 cross-compiler which runs on Linux and can generate 32-bit Windows executables.